# Proving $\log(n+k)$ is $O(log(n))$ for an arbitrary constant $k$?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I must only use the definition of Big O:

$f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ iff there are constants $C > 0$ and $N > 0$ such
that for all $n > N$, $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$.

I know how to do this using limits, but that is not allowed for this problem--we must come up with a constant of sorts. I've tried making $C=log(b)$, but that really doesn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$n+k\leq n+n=2n\leq n\cdot n= n^2$$
for all integers $n\geq \max\{k,2\}$, it follows that
$$ \log(n+k)\leq \log(n^2)=2\log n$$
for all $n\geq \max\{k,2\}$.

Comment: Nice proof, thank you. One thing that troubled me was the intuition behind your range of $n$. So I made a chart of $n$, $n+b$, and $n^2$ for various $b$ values, and I noticed that $n^2$ always eclipsed $n+b$ when $n\geq b/2$. Is this related to your choice of $n$? And can I use this fact in my proof?

Comment: I picked $n\geq k$ so that $n+k\leq 2n$, and $n\geq 2$ so that $2n\leq n^2$, but it's possible that a smaller $N$ could be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The log function is monotonic increasing because $\log x=\int_1^x\frac {1}{y}\;dy$.

For $x\geq 0$ we have  $\log (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x}\frac {1}{y}\;dy \leq \int_1^{1+x}1\;dy=x.$

So for $n>2|k|$ we have $$(\log n)-\frac {|k|}{n-|k|}\leq$$ $$\leq\log n-\log \left(1+\frac {|k|}{n-|k|}\right)=$$  $$=\log (n-|k|)\leq \log (n+k)\leq \log (n+|k|)=$$ $$=\log n+\log \left(1+\frac {|k|}{n}\right)\leq$$ $$\leq (\log n)+\frac {|k|}{n}.$$ Dividing by $\log n$ when  $n\geq\max (e^2,2|k|)$ we have   $$\frac {1}{2}\leq 1-\frac {1}{\log n}\leq  1-\frac {|k|}{n-|k|}\cdot \frac {1}{\log n}\leq $$    $$\leq \frac {\log (n+k)}{\log n}\leq 1+\frac {|k|}{n\log n}\leq 1+\frac {|k|}{e^2\log n}\leq 1+\frac {|k|}{2e^2}.$$